# Attach an image to a test report in MSTest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest

We are using Visual Studio 2010 connected to Team Foundation Server 2010 and we use MSTest to create our unit tests.

**Is it possible to attach an image to a test report, so when a test fails we can visualize something?**

This image can for example be a screenshot of the application for UI tests or a graph visualizing measurement data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`TestContext.AddResultFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.addresultfile) method:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Passed)
            TestContext.AddResultFile(testPassedFile);
        else
            TestContext.AddResultFile(testFailedFile);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {

    }

    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @pfernandez "Passed" and "Failed" are different words with different meanings I guess...