# Add a failure screenshot to an Nunit test

Tags: c#, nunit

I have an Nunit test which is doing some automated UI testing.

I know with MSTest you can add a screenshot into the results (see [Attach an image to a test report in MSTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995017/attach-an-image-to-a-test-report-in-mstest))

Is there something similar in nunit? Can I add a picture into the test results somehow? I've done a bit of looking but couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: Not with NUnit, no. What are you using for the UI Automation? Selenium? Selenium does have support for screenshots if you've gone that route.

Comment: I am using selenium, and i know how to take the screenshots, what im trying to do is to associate those back to the testresults

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for NUnit's [TestContext.AddTestAttachment(file)](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext#addtestattachment-37)

So you could do something like this in Selenium and NUnit:

```
// Get the screenshot from Selenium WebDriver and save it to a file
Screenshot screenshot = driver.GetScreenshot();
string screenshotFile = Path.Combine(TestContext.CurrentContext.WorkDirectory,
    "my_screenshot.png");
screenshot.SaveAsFile(screenshotFile, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

// Add that file to NUnit results
TestContext.AddTestAttachment(screenshotFile, "My Screenshot");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're prepared to alter the way you write your tests, a workable solution is to create an execution wrapper for your test logic.  This wrapper handles exceptions by taking a screenshot before control flow returns to the NUnit runner.

[See this solution for more details and code samples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33347267/998793).

Comment: Hey this doesn't really relate to my question. I know how to take screenshots. What i cant do is embed them in the test results.

Comment: Ok, apologies for the misunderstanding. If you are trying to actually view the screenshots within the NUnit application itself following a test run, I'm not able to offer a solution.  
The solution I linked to could however be used to generate log output (potentially in html form) which associates the screenshot file with each test result.  This is what I do for use on a build server, and it would work  running locally too - you could even script your build tool to open this for you after a test run.